# Executing SQL directly; no cursor, moving from development to live

Tags: php, sql-server

I've read through several posts on here in regards to the following error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Executing SQL
>   directly; no cursor.

However I can't seem to find out why it is working on my development server but not on my live server. From what I can tell, the user has the correct permissions in SSMS, and the PHP ini files are identical.

How I'm calling my stored proc (works in development):

```
$tsql = 'EXEC '.SITE_DATABASE.'.'.$db_procedure.' '.$params_new.'';

$result = $this->db->single($tsql);
```

The single function passes the SQL to the following code, but is throwing an exception:

```
$params = array();
$options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->handle, $sql, $params, $options) or $this->setError('Unable to query database:', sqlsrv_errors(), $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
      throw new Exception("Query failed:\n" . var_export(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

return $stmt;
```

The user for the SQL Server Management Studio has been granted execute on both servers, and as I said the PHP ini files are identical. Are there any permissions which might be why it doesn't work on the live server, that I have missed? If not, why is:

```
$options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
```

an issue on Live but not Dev when the servers are identically set up? (One is a clone of the other).

Comment: Is the native client installed on the machine identical (i.e. both version 11). It could be the SQL driver, [How to determine the version and edition of SQL Server and its components](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185)

Comment: @Liam one is a clone of the other, both have version 11 yes.

Comment: The options being set expects a resultset to come back.  So is the query or stored proc returning a result set?

Comment: @richardb the stored proc is rather large, and does a lot of updates and such, but right at the end it returns 0 - and the stored proc has not been changed on the live server.

Comment: That's just the return code.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678065/stored-procedure-fails-when-performing-update  "Try removing "Scrollable"=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC option from the call. "

Comment: @richard if I try running it through sqlsrv_query without $options, it won't run at all. - it works with options on my development server.

Comment: Tidying up the stored proc gave partial results, but still not consistent with my Development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in my case was simply a overlooked debug select statement which hadn't been commented out. (Yes I feel rather silly now!)

Commenting out this fixed the issue and it ran on Live.